# Single Method handling multiple SerialPort.DataReceived events with lock

Tags: c#, event-handling, serial-port, locking

I open multiple serial ports and assign the DataReceived event to a single method. If now multiple com ports receive at the same time something, **SerialPort_DataReceived** is called parallel(?) so i tried to use **lock** so that only one event could be handled at the same time.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Text;

namespace MainApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private SerialConnectionHandler m_SerialConnectionHandler;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            m_SerialConnectionHandler = new SerialConnectionHandler();
            m_SerialConnectionHandler.ResponseReceived += SerialConnectionHandler_ResponseReceived;
        }

        private void SerialConnectionHandler_ResponseReceived(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Do something.
        }
    }

    public class SerialConnectionHandler
    {
        private List<SerialPort> m_SerialConnections;
        private List<SerialCommand> m_CommandQueue;
        private object m_DataReceivedLock;

        public event EventHandler ResponseReceived;

        public SerialConnectionHandler()
        {
            m_SerialConnections = new List<SerialPort>();
            m_CommandQueue = new List<SerialCommand>();
            m_DataReceivedLock = new object();

            foreach (var comPortName in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
            {
                var newSerialPort = new SerialPort(comPortName);
                newSerialPort.DataReceived += SerialPort_DataReceived;

                var newSerialCommand = new SerialCommand(comPortName, "Command", "Response");

                newSerialPort.Open();
                newSerialPort.Write(newSerialCommand.Command, 0, newSerialCommand.Command.Length);
                m_SerialConnections.Add(newSerialPort);
            }
        }

        private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            lock (m_DataReceivedLock)
            {
                var serialPort = (SerialPort)sender;

                var receivedContent = new byte[serialPort.BytesToRead];
                serialPort.Read(receivedContent, 0, receivedContent.Length);

                // Clear in buffer.
                serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();

                // Do something which could lead to problems if multiple com ports receive at the same time something.
                foreach (var command in m_CommandQueue.FindAll(command => command.SerialPortName.Equals(serialPort.PortName)))
                {
                    if (command.ExpectedResponse.Equals(receivedContent.ToString()))
                    {
                        ResponseReceived?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());

                        m_CommandQueue.Remove(command);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class SerialCommand
    {
        public string SerialPortName { get; }
        public byte[] Command { get; }
        public string ExpectedResponse { get; }

        public SerialCommand(string serialPortName, string command, string expectedResponse)
        {
            SerialPortName = serialPortName;
            Command = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
            ExpectedResponse = expectedResponse;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is now, could **lock** lead to missed received content due to the fact that not every event is handled immediately? I'm calling **SerialPort.Read()** and **SerialPort.DiscardInBuffer()** from **inside** the lock block.

Comment: No, the thread will block if the lock is already in use until it's free. I don't see why it's necessary though. You're not using a shared resource in the handler, so there's no need to use a lock.

Comment: Never, *never*, **never** call DiscardInBuffer() in code that receives data.  You've called ReadExisting(), that emptied the buffer so it is completely unnecessary.  It *will* go wrong when another byte is received right after you called ReadExisting.  Which happens entirely too rarely to ever allow you to debug the data loss.  Worst kind of threading race bug since it doesn't have anything to do with threads that you created, the other thread here is a kernel thread used by the device driver.  No lock can fix that.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not using ReadExisting(). I'm using Read() - edited the example to look like i'm using it. Does this change anything on your described problem?